# How to transform a list of objects into an outer new object of objects?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given this collection of courses, there is a list of subjects that are composed of objects. Is it possible to create an aggregation to create a new field `newSubjects` that maps all subjects by their ids? For example, given this collection how to transform the `subjects` entries from :

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("623e2f0cb242ee9367eb3c9f"),
    subjects: [ { id: '1', name: 'math' }, { id: '2', name: 'physics' } ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("623e2f17b242ee9367eb3ca0"),
    subjects: [ { id: '1', name: 'math' }, { id: '3', name: 'biology' } ]
  }
]
```

into:

```
{
  newSubjects: { '1': { id: '1', name: 'math' }, '2': { id: '2', name: 'physics' } }
}
{
  newSubjects: { '1': { id: '1', name: 'math' }, '3': { id: '3', name: 'biology' } }
}
```

Using JavaScript I could do with this expression:

`db.courses.find().forEach(x => print({"newSubjects": Object.fromEntries(new Map(x.subjects.map(s => [s.id, s])))}))`

I'm trying to figure out an aggregation to accomplish this but haven't succeeded with `$addField` and `$map` yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query:

Only need one aggregate stage to compound the result you want. In this stage you can use a `$map` to iterate for every value and return a new one. This new one will have `k` and `v` fields.

- `k` field will be the object key (1, 2, 3...)
- `v` field will be the value field (the object with {id:..., name:...})

And wrapped by `$arrayToObject` to translate `k` and `v` to the desired object.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "newSubjects": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$$ROOT.subjects",
            "in": {
              "k": "$$this.id",
              "v": {
                "id": "$$this.id",
                "name": "$$this.name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-Y3eXNbTt4A)

Comment: Got it. Thanks, J.F.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
{
"$project": {
  "newSubjects": {
    "$arrayToObject": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$subjects",
        "as": "s",
        "in": {
          k: "$$s.id",
          v: "$$s"
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
 ])
```

Explained:

Map the array with the necessary k,v suitable for arrayToObject to be projected as newSubjects

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y6iWft4Qkmp)

Comment: I appreciated your help, R2D2, it's good to know this option too. Thanks.